# Minikube's CoreDNS fails to resolve names from JVM

Tags: kubernetes, dns, jvm, minikube, coredns

Our JVM services (based on Java SE 8/Scala/Finagle) have problems resolving DNS names. I have checked `coredns` deployment logs in `kube-system` namespace and found out that `java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName()` is querying for `ANY` record type.

If I check name resolution via `nslookup` I can confirm that `ANY` record type is not resolvable, but `A` or `AAAA` records are:

```
# kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup -type=a weather.mab.matjazmav.test
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   dev-proxy.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.100.187.185

# kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup -type=any weather.mab.matjazmav.test
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

*** Can't find weather.mab.matjazmav.test: No answer
```

My question is, how can I make Minikube's CoreDNS respond to `ANY` query, or how can I force `java.net.InetAddress` to send `A` or `AAAA` query?

**EDIT:**
It turned out that we used old NS provider that ships with Java SE 8 (`sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1=dns,sun`) see my answer for details.

Comment: I've tested in my minikube and can't get this issue, i tested with an external dns and internal (service). What is your minikube version? Where is the place of the DNS you are trying to reach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two possible solutions:

**1. Use CoreDNS rewrite plugin**

Rewrite query types from `ANY` to `A`. Here is a link to the documentation: https://coredns.io/plugins/rewrite/

**2. Use default NS provider inside JVM**

This applies only if you run on Jave SE 8 or older. **Java SE 9 removed this system property**, read more here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-removed-features.html#JDK-8134577

Java SE 8 ships with two NS providers `default` and `dns,sun`. `default` provider  uses system's NS provider while `dns,sun` uses some old NS implementation.

To use `default` NS provider simply set the following property:

```
sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1=default
```

Read more here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

Also this is a nice read: https://medium.com/@maheshsenni/host-name-resolution-in-java-80301fea465a